# script to monthly copy files to directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I would like to copy several `.txt` files from one windows share (can be 1-10 files, same creation date) to a target folder which should be named after the current month.

```
source: \\sharename\folder\file01.txt
target: \\sharename\folder\December\file01.txt
```

What would be the fastest way to archive this ?

What I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\sharename\folder\" |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-3) } |
    Copy-Item -Destination "\\sharename\folder"
```

This just copies the files which is ok but the whole *copy it to a monthly new created folder* is missing... I simply have no clue

Comment: Hi, have you tried anything ? Please include some code in your question (you can edit it) so we can help you :)

Comment: get-childitem -Path "\\sharename\folder\" |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-3)} | 
    copy-item -destination "\\sharename\folder"

so this just copys the files which is ok but the whole "copy it to a monthly new created folder is missing"...i simply have no clue...

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Date -UFormat "%B"
```

will give you the complete month name (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) for more information)

Then you can use it like this :

```
#store month name
$month = Get-Date -UFormat "%B"

#build destination path
$destination = "\\sharename\folder\$month\"

#creates the directory if it does not exist
if(-not (Test-Path $destination)) {
    New-Item $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

#copies the item
Copy-Item -Destination "\\sharename\folder\$month\"
```

Answer (score 0):

With batch I belive you can do something like this

```
forfiles -p "\\sharename\folder\" -s -m *.txt /D -30 /C "cmd /c move @file "\\sharename\folder\December\"
```

This should move all .txt files older than 30 days to your target-folder. However, to automaticly create folders named after the current month would require a lot more I suppose. But if "date" would be ok, you could do this.

```
set datetimef=%date:~-4%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
if not exist "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%" mkdir "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%"
```

This will create a folder like "ddmmyyyy". You can customize it by removing some of the "time:~x,x%" parts...

Comment: so this is my solution so long:

    set datetimef=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%
    if not exist "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%" mkdir "\\sharename\folder \%datetimef%"

forfiles -p "\\sharename\folder\source" -s -m *.xml /D -3 /C "cmd /c copy @file "\\sharename\folder\%datetimef%" 

and it seems to work ...

Comment: You missed the closing quote `"` in the `forfiles` command line; and you need to escape the quotes around the path after `cmd /C` like `\"`, or replace them by `0x22`...

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation, and awards the answer provider 15 rep points. Only 1 answer can be accepted. Once you reach 15 rep points you will have the privilege to up vote answers as well. You can up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other people's questions. An up vote awards the answer provider 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ...

```
$Local:LastMonthTimeStamp = Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMM")
# as string like "201511" for last month
$Local:SourceBaseDir      =  "\\Server\Share\Folder"
$Local:SourceFileName     =  "*.txt"
$Local:TargetBaseDir      =  "\\Server\Share\ArchiveFolder"
$Local:TargetDirectory    =  (New-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path$TargetBaseDir -ChildPath $LastMonthTimeStamp)  -Type Container -Force).FullName
# creates the monthly archive folder and returns the target path
# like: \\Server\Share\ArchiveFolder\201511

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceBaseDir -Filter $SourceFileName | Where-Object { 
    ((($_.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyyMM")) -like $LastMonthTimeStamp) } | ForEach-Object { 
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination$TargetDirectory -Force
}
```